Download github issue attachments from private repos
I want to download the attachments in a GitHub issue programmatically.
Using the GitHub API Python SDK I can authenticate and get the Issues and comments for a private repository. The API doesn't have a method to obtain the attachments in the issues, but the body includes their URLs.
If the repo is public, a GET request works just fine, but if the repo is private, I can't get it to work. I've tried several combination of Authentication headers with token, bearer, etc... but all blindly since I can't find any documentation.
When done on an authenticated session from the browser it uses the session cookies to eventually redirect to an AWS file for the download. I don't have these session cookies (not that I know of) when authenticated via token using the API.
I can find several people asking for the same in different forums over the years and none has an answer.

Have you found any answer so far?

nothing. I can only make it work for public repos

I faced the same problem some time ago, the solution I found was to host the files on AWS S3, and add the url to the file in the body of the issue. It's not the best solution, but it helped me
